# Matlab recessionplot

Tags: matlab

I have seen that on matlab there is the cmd recessionplot that adds bar of recessions to plots. But that is for the official US dates, do you know if there is a similar command for the european crisis as certified by cepr?

Comment: Could you show an example of this plot? Do you mean this [command](https://se.mathworks.com/help/econ/recessionplot.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)?

Comment: yes exactly the cmd is simply
recessionplot

Comment: Vandalizing questions isn’t allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it manually. 
Here's an example of shading an area behind a plot. You just need to adapt the colors and the dates for the recession.

A very basic example about shading an area in a plot. Shading an area bounded by a curve might be of interest as well.

```
figure;
ha = area([4 6], [10 10]);
hold on
plot(1:10, 1:10,'r')
axis([1 10 1 10])
hold off
```